# How to form pm.test assertions in Postman

Tags: postman, postman-newman

Given the following transaction reply how would I form a pm.test assertion for it?

```
{
    "data": {
        "clearEmployerClaim": true
    }
}
```

This isn't working for me:

```
pm.test("clear employer claim status returned", () => { 
    const response = pm.response.json(); 
    pm.expect(response.clearEmployerClaim).to.be.true;
});
```

I would normally do it like this but I'm getting type errors when running this via Jenkins/Newman. It works fine run via Postman.

```
tests["C536773447 clear employer claim status returned"] = body.data.clearEmployerClaim === true;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one level here.

`pm.expect(response.clearEmployerClaim).to.be.true;` --> `pm.expect(response.data.clearEmployerClaim).to.be.true;`